# Cisco DHCP Router

Tags: cisco, dhcp

I have come across an issue and I’m not sure on how to resolve. I’m trying to get the router to assign the PC’s within my network IP addresses. I have excluded the ones which i wish to not be used however it seems to allocate the wrong addresses.

For example, the network address is 10.10.10.0, the router is 10.10.10.1 and I wish to exclude addresses 10.10.10.1 to 10.10.10.10. So the first PC will be 10.10.10.11 however it provides the first PC with an IP address 10.0.0.1? I have included the coding as an image, please could someone advise?

Many thanks!

```
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.10.1 10.10.10.10 
ip dhcp pool MyCompany 
 network 10.10.10.0 255.0.0.0 
 default-router 10.10.10.1
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the router configuration. Paste the text configuration into the question using the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`).

Comment: ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.10.1 10.10.10.10           ip dhcp pool MyCompany                                                       network 10.10.10.0 255.0.0.0                                            default-router 10.10.10.1

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Network Engineering!  The subnet mask in your network statement is incorrect.

It should be 255.255.255.0

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I am new to this. However now it begins the IP’s from 10.10.10.12 instead of 10.10.10.11. Is there any indication why this is?

Answer (score 3):

Use "show ip dhcp binding" to see if the IP is still bound to a PC. I think its default to 24 hours. You might need to clear the binding to use the 10.10.10.11

Comment: Thank you for your help! It’s successfully working now.